# Weird Regex issue - Proper Debugging Methods for PHP

Tags: php, jquery, regex

Can anyone explain why this regex is failing? It works in an online RegEx tester

http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php which uses the PHP `preg_match` the same as I do.

Here's pretty much all the relevant code.

Yes the regex works fine but the php code doesn't. I need to remember when stuff should work and doesn't it's usually a typo. In this case I concatenated my pattern to my string by typing a `.` as opposed to a `,`, I find that to be very hard typo to notice. As such one trick that I do with syntax errors I can't seem to find is to retype the code in question. Of course in this case my typo didn't result in invalid syntax.

Another thing I probably should have done is check apache error log because the fact that preg_match was receiving the incorrect number of parameters should have resulted in an error.

I am new to using ajax calls to php scripts which return json and I am not use to not seeing the php errors that are generated. In the past when working with java clients, I have always used a php curl client for testing the webservice's response. I was rushed and I skipped that step on this project.

What methods do you use to properly debug your php?

```
//$colors  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['color']);
$colors='333333,cbafff';

 function addcolor($colors,$cart_id, $dbh) {
    //insert color or scheme into cart
    //If succeeds return success, if fail return failure
    $stmt2=$dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO cart (cart_id,item_id) values (:cart_id,:item_id)");
    $stmt2->bindValue(':cart_id',$cart_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $color_array=split(",",$colors);
    foreach ($color_array as $color) {
        $color=trim($color);

        if (!preg_match("/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$/".$color)) {
            return array("result"=>"error: Invalid Color $color");
            break;
        }
        $stmt2->bindValue(':item_id',$color,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if (!($stmt2->execute())) {
            return array("result"=>"failure ". $stmt2->getCode());
            break;
        }
    }
    return array("result"=>"success");
}
```

jQuery script

```
// to use surround anchor tags with div (id=colors). Set color or scheme id as href value. On click the item is posted to the web service.
// To do improve response handling from webservice.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img a").live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var item = $(this).attr( 'href' );
        var rev = $(this).attr('rev');
        var action ="add";
        if (rev == "1") {
            action = "add";
            $(this).attr('rev',"2");
        }
        else {          
            action = "remove";
            $(this).attr('rev',"1");
        }
        var jqxhr = $.post("webservice.php", { action: action, color: item }, function(data) {
            var result=data.result;
            if (result!="success") {
                alert(result);
            }
        }, "json")
        .error(function() {         
            alert("error: unable to contact web service"); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That does work. Reports a match for me.

Comment: It works fine: http://3v4l.org/prSLa

Comment: Works fine for me as well - you most likely have something that you don't expect in `$color`. Try to `var_dump` it and check.

Comment: `return smth; break;` - what?

Comment: It works fine, maybe you got confused with negative sign? 
@raina77ow maybe it is excerpt from function, yeah but anyway `break` after `return` isn't good :)

Comment: what raina77ow tries to say: you don't need the `break` cause the function will exit with the `return` statement. so the `break` can never be reached.

Comment: @Codeguy007 what result do you get now and what do you expect?

Comment: @raina77ow I believe this is valid syntax. Even though a bit redundant, it might be helpful in development (`return` gets commented out => `break` makes sense)

Comment: Yes, I understand what he's saying but that's not why my regular expression is failing.

Comment: @JanDvorak `break` from what, `if` branch? But anyway, my point was actually about the validity of the question itself. Given as it is, there's no technical problem shown.

Comment: Well 333333 matches the regular expression so the if statement should be skipped but it's not it's returning the array.

Comment: @Codeguy007 What does `var_dump($color);` output?

Comment: @Codeguy007 If the regex matches, the `return array` shouldn't be triggered.

Comment: That will take me a minute because this being called in by an ajax script.

Comment: @Codeguy007 If you use Chrome, the Network debug panel can be VERY useful to do this stuff. Firebug on firefox has the same sort of panel.

Comment: Show us the full function, and, once again, log the `$color` variable

Comment: @raina it has nothing to do with the client code. Client just displays the same message as the php script sends back.

Comment: break is there because the whole thing is in a foreach loop.

Comment: @Codeguy007 Can't you just install XDebug and, well, use it? This would greatly help you in this case (and in zillions others as well, eventually).

Comment: @Codeguy007 If you execute `return`, the loop will _not_ continue, don't worry

Comment: @raina77ow this may not be possible on a hosted server.

Comment: Why is my question being voted down?

Comment: @JanDvorak While I appreciate your attempts of being helpful, this issue might have been gone and dusted if the OP bothered to post the whole code (X) instead of obviously correct regex (Y).

Comment: @Codeguy007 People are voting your question down as your example works fine. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Does preg_match returns you 0 or false ? Might help the diagnostic.

Comment: Yes the preg_match is failing.

Comment: You are likely to have space issues ...

Comment: @Codeguy007, Define "failing". I don't know what this word means in this context.  www.php.net suggests one of the following outputs:
`preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.`

Comment: I added $color=trim($color) and I still get the error.

Comment: Well if you run the code outside my program it runs without error. I would have to recode it to see if the function is returning 0 or false as it's called by ajax so I don't see the output.

Comment: So the problem wasn't elsewhere it was a typo. Thanks for voting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong, you're concatenating instead of giving a second parameter to preg_match:

`preg_match("/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$/".$color)`

```
preg_match("/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$/", $color)
```

Comment: Hey, why did you unaccepted my answer?